# Multiple Orderer redundancy in Kafka based network

Tags: apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

We're stuck configuring a fabric network based on 3 orgs with 1 peer each and 2 kafka-based orderers. For kafka ordering we use 4 kafka nodes with 3 zookeepers. It's deployed on some AWS ec2 instances as follows:

1: Org1

2: Org2

3: Org3

4: orderer0, orderer1, kafka0, kafka1, kafka2, kafka3, zookeeper0, zookeeper1, zookeeper2

The whole of the ordering nodes plus kafka cluster is located in the same machine for connectivity reasons (read somewhere they must be in the same machine to avoid these problems)

During our test, we try taking down the first orderer (orderer0) for redundancy testing with docker stop. We expected the network to continue working through orderer1, but instead it dies and stops working.

Looking at the peer's console, I can see some errors.

> Could not connect to any of the endpoints: [orderer0.example.com:7050, orderer1.example.com:8050]

Find attached the content of the files related to the configuration of the system.

Orderer + kafka + zk

```
#
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#
version: '2'

services:

  zookeeper0.example.com:
    container_name: zookeeper0.example.com
    extends:
      file: docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: zookeeper0.example.com
    logging:
     driver: "json-file"
     options:
      max-size: "1m"
      max-file: "3"

  zookeeper1.example.com:
    container_name: zookeeper1.example.com
    extends:
      file: docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: zookeeper1.example.com
    logging:
     driver: "json-file"
     options:
      max-size: "1m"
      max-file: "3"

  zookeeper2.example.com:
    container_name: zookeeper2.example.com
    extends:
      file: docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: zookeeper2.example.com
    logging:
     driver: "json-file" 
     options:
      max-size: "1m"
      max-file: "3"

  kafka0.example.com:
    container_name: kafka0.example.com
    extends:
      file: docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: kafka0.example.com
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper0.example.com
      - zookeeper1.example.com
      - zookeeper2.example.com
      - orderer0.example.com
      - orderer1.example.com
    logging:
     driver: "json-file"
     options:
      max-size: "1m"
      max-file: "3"

  kafka1.example.com:
    container_name: kafka1.example.com
    extends:
      file: docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: kafka1.example.com
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper0.example.com
      - zookeeper1.example.com
      - zookeeper2.example.com
      - orderer0.example.com
      - orderer1.example.com
    logging:
     driver: "json-file"
     options:
      max-size: "1m"
      max-file: "3"

  kafka2.example.com:
    container_name: kafka2.example.com
    extends:
      file: docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: kafka2.example.com
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper0.example.com
      - zookeeper1.example.com
      - zookeeper2.example.com
      - orderer0.example.com
      - orderer1.example.com
    logging:
     driver: "json-file"
     options:
      max-size: "1m"
      max-file: "3"

  kafka3.example.com:
    container_name: kafka3.example.com
    extends:
      file: docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: kafka3.example.com        
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper0.example.com
      - zookeeper1.example.com
      - zookeeper2.example.com
      - orderer0.example.com
      - orderer1.example.com
    logging:
     driver: "json-file"
     options:
      max-size: "1m"
      max-file: "3"

  orderer0.example.com:
    container_name: orderer0.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.1.0
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_LISTEN_PORT=7050
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/orderer/msp
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/etc/hyperledger/crypto/orderer/tls/ca.crt, /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peerOrg1/tls/ca.crt, /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peerOrg2/tls/ca.crt, /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peerOrg3/tls/ca.crt]
    logging:
     driver: "json-file"
     options:
      max-size: "1m"
      max-file: "3"
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderers
    command: orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    volumes:
        - ./channel:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - ./channel/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer0.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/orderer
        - ./channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peerOrg1
        - ./channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peerOrg2
        - ./channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer0.org3.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peerOrg3
    depends_on:
        - kafka0.example.com
        - kafka1.example.com
        - kafka2.example.com
        - kafka3.example.com

  orderer1.example.com:
    container_name: orderer1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.1.0
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GEN ERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_LISTEN_PORT=8050
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/orderer/msp
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/etc/hyperledger/crypto/orderer/tls/ca.crt, /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peerOrg1/tls/ca.crt, /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peerOrg2/tls/ca.crt, /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peerOrg3/tls/ca.crt]
    logging:
     driver: "json-file"
     options:
      max-size: "1m"
      max-file: "3"
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderers
    command: orderer
    ports:
      - 8050:7050
    volumes:
        - ./channel:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - ./channel/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer1.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/orderer
        - ./channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peerOrg1
        - ./channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peerOrg2
        - ./channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer0.org3.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peerOrg3
    depends_on:
        - kafka0.example.com
        - kafka1.example.com
        - kafka2.example.com
        - kafka3.example.com
```

Peer and Ca from Org2

```
#
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#
version: '2'

services:

  ca.org2.example.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.1.0
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/efa7d0819b7083f6c06eb34da414acbcde79f607b9ce26fb04dee60cf79a389a_sk
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/efa7d0819b7083f6c06eb34da414acbcde79f607b9ce26fb04dee60cf79a389a_sk
    ports:
      - "8054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca_peerOrg2

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file:   base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org2.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
    ports:
      - 8051:7051
      - 8053:7053
    volumes:
        - ./channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer
    logging:
     driver: "json-file"
     options:
      max-size: "1m"
      max-file: "3"
    extra_hosts:
      - "orderer0.example.com:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
      - "orderer1.example.com:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
      - "kafka0.example.com:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
      - "kafka1.example.com:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
      - "kafka2.example.com:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
      - "kafka3.example.com:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
```

Orderer base

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

services:

  orderer-base:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=error
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      # kafka
      - CONFIGTX_ORDERER_ORDERERTYPE=kafka
      - CONFIGTX_ORDERER_KAFKA_BROKERS=[kafka0.example.com,kafka1.example.com,kafka2.example.com,kafka3.example.com]
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_RETRY_SHORTINTERVAL=1s
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_RETRY_SHORTTOTAL=30s
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
```

Kafka base

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

services:

  zookeeper:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper
    environment:
      - ZOO_SERVERS=server.1=zookeeper0.example.com:2888:3888 server.2=zookeeper1.example.com:2888:3888 server.3=zookeeper2.example.com:2888:3888
    restart: always

  kafka:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-kafka
    restart: always
    environment:
      - KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES=103809024 # 99 * 1024 * 1024 B
      - KAFKA_REPLICA_FETCH_MAX_BYTES=103809024 # 99 * 1024 * 1024 B
      - KAFKA_UNCLEAN_LEADER_ELECTION_ENABLE=false
      - KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS=2
      - KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR=3
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper0.example.com:2181,zookeeper1.example.com:2181,zookeeper2.example.com:2181
    logging:
     driver: "json-file"
     options:
      max-size: "1m"
      max-file: "3"
```

configtx.yaml

```
Organizations:


    - &OrdererOrg

        Name: OrdererMSP


        ID: OrdererMSP


        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp

    - &Org1

        Name: Org1MSP


        ID: Org1MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp

        AnchorPeers:

            - Host: peer0.org1.example.com
              Port: 7051

    - &Org2

        Name: Org2MSP

        ID: Org2MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp

        AnchorPeers:

            - Host: peer0.org2.example.com
              Port: 7051

    - &Org3

        Name: Org3MSP


        ID: Org3MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/msp

        AnchorPeers:

            - Host: peer0.org3.example.com
              Port: 7051



################################################################################
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults


    OrdererType: kafka

    Addresses:
        - orderer0.example.com:7050
        - orderer1.example.com:7050


    BatchTimeout: 2s


    BatchSize:

        MaxMessageCount: 10

        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 98 MB

        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    Kafka:
        Brokers:
            - kafka0.example.com:9092
            - kafka1.example.com:9092
            - kafka2.example.com:9092
            - kafka3.example.com:9092

    Organizations:


################################################################################
Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    Organizations:


################################################################################
Profiles:

    ThreeOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
                    - *Org3
    ThreeOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
                - *Org3
```

May it be a configuration error? Connection problems are almost discarded because running the same network on a local machine gives the same result.

Thanks in advance
Regards

Comment: You are starting up two Orderers, both of them with the same configuration. Are you sure that both containers are running? Could you try executing the "docker ps" comnand in your CLI and paste the result? I thinkt that the problem will be that both orderers aren't starting up

Comment: First, should there be any problem with starting two Orderers with the same configuration? As long as they listen to different ports. Second, I confirmed the second orderer, orderer1, is running. It writes logs and shows transactions. It looks like its working as an slave of orderer0, and when orderer0 is down, it becomes useless

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you. However, the problem is that each Node (Peer, Orderer...) should have its own identificer for the MSP, and in your case, both of them have the samee ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP.

Comment: Yeah makes sense, thanks. I changed OrdererMSP to Orderer0MSP and Orderer1MSP, then I changed the configtx.yaml to match the new definition. Now I'm getting an error msg from the peer: "Failed connecting to orderer1:7050, certificate is valid for orderer0, not orderer1".

Comment: I think that your crypto material isn't correct. Have you changed the cryptoconfig.yaml before creating the crypto material? In the cryptoconfig.yaml you define the crypto material that you are going to create. There you should define both orderers. In the configtx,yaml, you also should make some changes.

Comment: Yep already fixed that, must have been some error in the upload because I repeated the same process and the certificate thing was fixed. Anyway, now I'm using two different LOCALMSPID and the result is the same. When I stop the first orderer, the second becomes useless. It doesn't show any log since I stop the first one. Thanks for your help btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it running smooth. Turns out the problem wasn't in docker-compose files, but in the version of fabric sdk for the web service. I was using **fabric-client** and **fabric-ca-client** both on version 1.1, and this was missing until 1.2. (More info https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABN-90)

Just to clarify, I was able to see transactions happening on both orderers because of the interconnection between them, but I was only attacking the first one. When that orderer went down, network would go dark.

I understood the way fabric deals with orderers, it points to the first orderer of the list, if it is down or unreachable, moves it to the bottom of the list and targets the next one. This is what's happening since 1.2, in older versions you have to code your own error controller so that it changes to the next orderer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it could be because of different network layer. Since it's a different compose file , docker do create different network layer for each composer.

Also, I don't see network mentioned in the yaml files.

Please check list of network layer using "docker network list".